# Best way to keep constants in android

Tags: java, android, constants

what is the best way in android to store constants to be consumed in java classes.
From what I know there are two ways:

1. res/strings
2. Creating an interface

from what I learned I think creating interface is not a safe practice. Am not sure if res/strings safe. Can someone let me know which is the safe and easy way to put application constants safely in android that can be consumed by other java classes in the same application.

Comment: If its only used by one class I use 'public static final String EXAMPLE = "foo"' else I put them in strings.xml

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: neither. `res/strings` is done for localization and you need a context to access the values, which could not always be available.

Comment: The best way is to declare a constant somehow and proceed further with your program.

Comment: What about BuildConfig? Gradle?

Answer (score 12):

I create a package **utils** and add a **Constant** class like this:

```
package utils;

public class Constant {

    public static final String API_KEY = "yourApikey";
    public static final int INT_ID = 0;
    //And more...

}
```

Then, you can call this properties from others classes and packages:

```
int int_id = Constant.INT_ID;
```

---

In response to Suni'l comment. One way to use constants without using the **static** keyword, would be to define the properties **within an interface** and then **implement** that interface in the class where you want to use those properties:

```
public interface Constant{
    String API_KEY = "yourApiKey";
    int INT_ID = 0;
}
```

And then, in your class:

```
public class YourClass implements Constant{

    int int_id = INT_ID;

}
```

Regards!

Comment: And.. why is this a good thing to do?

Comment: Is there any way to declare string in constant without using static keyword and use them in other classes?

Answer (score 4):

If they are really Constants that you set once and that may vary between builds, e.g. Api Urls and the sorts, you should use `BuildConfig`.

in your build.gradle you can add:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "GCM_PROJECT_KEY", "\"1234567890\""
    }
}
```

This will generate a `public final String GCM_PROJECT_KEY` in `your.package.BuildConfig` which you can use. This class should also be used everywhere you use your application id, version or version name.

Also, this is the way to go when using multiple flavors. You just need to move your constants from buildTypes to flavors.